# Geoserver WMS WMTS offset EPSG:3059

Tags: geoserver, epsg, geowebcache

How is it possible that Geoserver WMS map works perfectly in GIS software but the same map cached using integrated GeoWebCache using the same coordinate system gives the same map in other location. I tried different data with EPSG:3059, but always the same offset.  Where should I look for a misconfiguration or what could be the problem?

Comment: How large is the offset? It's odd, because LKS92 should be compatible (line up reasonably well) with WGS84.

Comment: offset is around 500 km to SE

Comment: when I look at the OpenLayers preview it looks ok - coordinates at different points are correct, but when I add wmts to arcgis, qgis and other clients map is offset

Comment: How did you define the gridset and how does it show in WMTS GetCapabilities?

Comment: [capabilities](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17615693/wmts-getcapabilities%20%285%29.xml)

Comment: [gridset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmjfwgvp0f67qae/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: The gridset bounds in the screen capture from user interface and bounds of GetCapabilities do not match. The latter are `<TopLeftCorner>189423.1434797966 457996.0</TopLeftCorner>`. I would try to calculate the 0 level bounds with calculator by selecting the lower-left coordinates and addind 256xresolution and 512xresolution for getting the top-right coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment but this does not solve the problem. Here is the picture of [offset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw6YzP5ymGbbNXJERmxWRDB6dlg1bGFWcmxzc3c2c2ZWN1Q0/view?usp=drivesdk)
WMS client is getting values like this somewhere: min x 573121 miny -75210 maxx 160959 maxy 1012768. Didn't find none of them in Capabilities. The map in the upper corner of the picture is the place where it should be an the rectangle is where WMTS wants to put the WMTS map.